# How to increase default timeout for SQL request sent from Cypress test?

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, cypress, cypress-custom-commands

I use cypress-sql-server plugin for sending SQL requests from Cypress tests. It works fine if the Data processed by the request is not large. But for big amounts of data the request fails by timeout which is 60 secs by default. cypress-sql-server npm package doesn't provide any information about timeout settings. How can I implement custom timeout e.g. something like this:

```
cy.sqlServer(query, { timeout: 90000 }).then(($data) => {
  console.log($data)
})
```

Comment: If the package itself does not allow to configure the timeout, you just cannot. Maybe you could mock nodejs timers with: https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/clock
This might help you to extend the "60 seconds". Also, why do you even test your DB directly? You should not test DB engines from cypress (unless you are developer of the engine :) )

**Edit**: As the package used isn't that convenient for exploring from its documentation, it was hard to tell the timeout is related to Cypress (read "Noname NoSurename" answer). I keep that  comment as I still insist on not testing your DB engine.

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/configuration#Timeouts - here is all timeouts. Redefine the desired variable. This file will be cypress.config.js for JavaScript apps or cypress.config.ts for TypeScript apps.

Comment: Not so easy unfortunatelly. Sure I tried these timeouts, but it looks like the plugin custom commands use their own timeouts

Comment: But your advise was helpful anyway. I tried to increase requestTimeout and requestTimeout which did not work. But after rechecking all available timeouts I came to desission that taskTimeout could solve the problem as custom commands are based on "task" usage. Thank you!